# Texttable - how to create a table from a for loop

Tags: python, supabase, texttable

I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9535954/printing-lists-as-tabular-data) and I want to format the output retrived from a database service to show it in cli when the python script is executed. I've installed [this module](https://pypi.org/project/texttable/) and I've this code at the moment but I'm unable to undertsand how I can append the data to a new row of the table I want to draw. The data are part of supabase response (sometimes it will fail to connect due to a proxy issue) but I get this error `texttable.ArraySizeError: array should contain 1 elements`. Is clear to me that I can't append the elements into the array, so how I can achive my scope correctly?

```py
supabase: Client = create_client(url, key)
print(supabase)
#
response = supabase.table('pdvList').select('*').execute()

total_rows = len(response.data)
total_columns = range(16)

table = Texttable() 
table.set_cols_align(['c'])
table.set_cols_valign(['m'])

table_rows = []
table_rows.append('ID, Nome brand, Cod. filiale, CPCO, Rag. sociale, Indirizzo, CAP, Città, Provincia, Telefono, IP, Gestione, VPN, Cod. Uakari, Front-end')

# Creating table
for r in range(total_rows):
    print(response.data[r]['ip_rete'])
    table_rows.append(f"{response.data[r]['id']}, {response.data[r]['nome_brand']}, {response.data[r]['cod_filiale']},{response.data[r]['cpco']}, {response.data[r]['rag_sociale']}, {response.data[r]['indirizzo']}, {response.data[r]['cap']}, {response.data[r]['citta']}, {response.data[r]['provincia']}, {response.data[r]['telefono']}, {response.data[r]['ip_rete']}, {response.data[r]['gestione']}, {response.data[r]['vpn']}, {response.data[r]['cod_uak']}, {response.data[r]['front_end']}")
# Adding rows to table
table.add_rows(table_rows)
# Drawing table
print(table.draw())
```

Probably I'm doing it in the wrong way, can I add a single row to the table inside a loop?I need to set the header first and then all the data. Thank you for the help

Comment: can't use use `if len(..) > 0:` to run it only when you have data?